# Update an instance retrieved with include

Tags: sequelize.js

Here is an instance `item` retrieved in sequelize 6.5.x with `include` model `Artwork` (ForSale item belongsTo Artwork):

```
      let item = await ForSale.findOne({  where: {id:id},   
                                        include: {
                                            model:Artwork,
                                            attributes:["uploader_id"]
                                        }
                            });
```

For `item`, can any update performed on fields from model `ForSale` as below:

```
item.name = "Joe";  //assign a new name to item
await item.save(); //<<==legal to update name field in ForSale?
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: Whenever you try to update `ForSale` own fields that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

No, i don't think it can work like in PHP Try :

```
item.update({name:'Joe'});
```